# csv to pdf file in java

Tags: java, pdf, csv, itext

I am trying to get a `csv` file parsed into a `pdf`. What I have so far is attached below.

My problem is with this code the file that ends up in the pdf cuts off at the first line of the csv file and I cant figure out why. [*examples attached*] Essentially I would like a pdf version of the csv file nothing manipulated. I am sure its an issue with how i am adding data to the itext pdf but I cant really find another way of forwarding an array to the pdf file. Any ideas on fixing the code or something simpler?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("data1.csv") ,'\'');
    String [] nextLine;
    while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
            System.out.println(nextLine[0]);
            String test; 
            test = nextLine[0];

            // step 1
            Document document = new Document();

            // step 2
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("Test.pdf"));

            // step 3
            document.open();

            // step 4
            PdfPTable arrayTable3 = new PdfPTable(1); 
            arrayTable3.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT); 

            Phrase phrase1 = new Phrase(nextLine[0]); 
            PdfPCell arrayDetailsCell3 = new PdfPCell(); 

            arrayDetailsCell3.addElement(phrase1); 

            // Add the cell to the table 
            arrayTable3.addCell(arrayDetailsCell3); 

            // Add table to the document 
            document.add(arrayTable3); 

            // step 5
            document.close();
    }
}
```

CSV file: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11365830/data1.csv 
PDF file: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11365830/Test.pdf

Comment: if you only use the first column- you don't really need csv... is that your std usecase?

Comment: Hi Frank, it would be nice if I could get the lines from individual coloumns but unfortunately the csv parser keeps giving me errors if I try to only display data from other columns. Like for instance if  i have the following code:System.out.println(nextLine[0]+nextLine[1]); I will get an out of bounds error. Have I misunderstood the parser function?  The csv is an output from a converter and I am trying to get that into a pdf format.

Comment: I guess the parser works though I don't know it. But what's definitely wrong is your iteration (while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null)) this is not right.. Overthink your whole code... are you sure that you want a "new Document();" for every line?

Comment: yikes cant believe i didnt see that. Yes I dont need a new document for every iteration... Thanks. And the parser is really there because I dont know of any other way to import in the csv file thats all. If you know of an easier way I would love to hear it! I  essentailly want to create a csv to pdf converter and this was the best way i can think of going about it.

Comment: I personally prefer the more native way with iterating over the lines and StringTokenizer for instance.. but that's just my opinion. Got any further questions or is your problem solved? If it's solved please write an answer or delete it- thx

Comment: Hi Frank, unfortunately that hadnt resolved my issue but I dont think I was asking my question correctly. I essentially just wanted to know how to take the value in the String [] variables and input them properly into a pdf using the itext library. I put together the answer from other posts in SO and turns it was rather trivial. In any case I will attach the answer in a comment!

Comment: not sure if this would help, but you can use [opencsv and iText to convert CSV to PDF easily](http://thinktibits.blogspot.com.au/2012/12/convert-csv-to-pdf-opencsv-itext-java-program-example.html). Refer to the link below for a tutorial. http://thinktibits.blogspot.com.au/2012/12/convert-csv-to-pdf-opencsv-itext-java-program-example.html

Comment: Thanks that helps! I ended up using similar code (posted above as solution)

Comment: please post an answer to mark your question as solved thx

Comment: @anand btw, if you're ever back here and want to collect the potential rep for your answer, lemme know and i'll delete my post. just wanted to clearly provide the answer to anyone who comes through

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution @anand came up with (anand had edited it into the question for lack of understanding how SO works).

```
public void createPdf(String filename) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    // step 1
    Document document = new Document();

    // step 2
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));

    // step 3
    document.open();

    // step 4
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("testing.csv") ,'\'');
    List< String[]> myEntries = reader.readAll();
    for (int i = 31; i < myEntries.size(); i++) {
        String[] strings = myEntries.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < strings.length; j++) {
             document.add(new Paragraph(strings[j] + "\n"));
        }
    }

    // step 5
    document.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set DEFAULT_SKIP_LINES to 0 in CSVReader.java