# How to populate SQLite Data into a TEXT file with tabularised form..?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

All My Records are going into Database perfectly.. but My need id when I click button, All data should be fetched from database and then populate all records in **MySample.txt** file within a folder. Please Help me I am very New in Android Domain. Millions Thanks

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.insert_data);


            SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(WardRobe_Contact.CATEGORY,s1);
            values.put(WardRobe_Contact.PRODUCT,s2);
            values.put(WardRobe_Contact.ITEM_NAME,s3);
            values.put(WardRobe_Contact.BRAND,s4);
            values.put(WardRobe_Contact.AGE_GROUP,s5);
            values.put(WardRobe_Contact.PURCHASE,s6);
            values.put(WardRobe_Contact.QUANTITY,s7);
            values.put(WardRobe_Contact.COST,s8);
            values.put(WardRobe_Contact.RECEIVED,s9);
            values.put(WardRobe_Contact.GIFTED,s10);
            values.put(WardRobe_Contact.GIFT_DATE,s11);
            values.put(WardRobe_Contact.DESCRIPTION,s12);
            values.put(WardRobe_Contact.WARD_REF,s13);
long items_entry = db.insert(WardRobe_Contact.TABLE_ITEM, null, values);
                db.close(); 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data Inserted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
}
```

Comment: **suggestion** : better way to avoid table in txt, export all data as CSV format

Comment: thnxx for quick reply sir, but may i able to convert that csv file to .PDF ? further in my project that data list have to be email to client

Comment: use this library to convert it,  [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/android/word-component/key-features.aspx) Aspose word lets you convert any document to any format

Comment: Sir, do u=you have any source code which you had done before ? please let me know any link or website or full complete example.. My email id is ahana000in@gmail.com

Comment: check this thread [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641945/csv-to-pdf-file-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641945/csv-to-pdf-file-in-java)

Comment: Thank you sir but frankly speaking, I didn't get the correct approach.. I am getting all my values correctly in TextView. Now  My intension is when user click a button , then all the values must be converted in to pdf format.... Have you any idea ?